# Export icon to bitmap image in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm having a massive bout of trouble with the following code sample:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.Icon.ToBitmap.Save("..\help.bmp", Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
    End Sub
End Class
```

The purpose is to export the icon as a bitmap file. However - it isn't generating any output. Any ideas?

Comment: Specify a full path. Why your Form's Icon? On `Form.Load()`? Is this your actual question? Btw, you probably want to save an Icon as PNG instead of BMP, so transparency can be preserved.

Comment: I tried specifying a full path. It didn't work. I need the form icon because it's user customizable and want an archival copy. Yes, it is an actual question, yes, I am using Form.Load but I did try other functions, and thank you for the advice. (Edit: it worked. Thanks.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works perfectly, you need to specify the **full exact path** to save the icon. I've tried this in my machine and it's working.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Icon.ToBitmap.Save("C:\Users\<user_name>\Desktop\hello.bmp", Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
End Sub
```

[image: Great bmp Image]